# Does "await Task.CompletedTask" do anything?

Tags: async-await

I'm curious about this statement:

`await Task.CompletedTask;`

I know that it nominally doesn't do anything practical, but what I'm wondering is whether it actually causes the running function to exit, then resume at the statement after the await, or whether it truly does nothing and doesn't interrupt the thread at all.

This might make a difference in the sense that it would cause the current run loop to complete and resume, and if the run loop is the main thread it would mean that UI changes got committed.

The documentation doesn't explain it, and I can't figure out a good way to decide which it is.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: I actually found this just after I posted: "When the await operator is applied to the operand that represents already completed operation, it returns the result of the operation immediately without suspension of the enclosing method." So I think the answer is that it doesn't interrupt the thread.

Comment: Yes, the method will only return if the Task is not completed i.e. `Task.CompletedTask.GetAwaiter().IsCompleted`, if it is completed, it will return the result on the same thread that called the method. As you can imagine, `Task.CompletedTask` has `true` for the above property.`

Answer (score 3):

> whether it actually causes the running function to exit, then resume at the statement after the await, or whether it truly does nothing and doesn't interrupt the thread at all.

[`await` will first test its awaitable to see if it is already complete, and if it is, it will continue executing synchronously](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

If you want to *force* an asynchronous function to yield, then use `await Task.Yield();`. Side note: this should be **extremely** rare in production code, but it's sometimes useful for unit tests.

Comment: Thanks. Adding await Task.Yield() made a big difference in my code and fixed most of the problems I was trying to address.