# Can I safely remove await Task.CompletedTask call at the end of a method?

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

I was looking over some old code and I found an `async` method doing some `async` stuff and at the end calling `await Task.CompletedTask;` like below:

```
    public async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        //some code
        //...

        await _someService.DoStuffAsync();
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

From what I read it seems safe to remove the last line, as it does not have a functional impact over the method execution, since the `Task.CompletedTask` will return a task that is already completed so it will not await it, but I have second thoughts about this.

Is it safe to delete the last line? Is it redundant?

Comment: You could possibly debate about having `return Task.CompletedTask` there. But `await Task.CompletedTask` doesn't make any sense. Of course `return Task.CompletedTask` would mean you'd have to change the signature (remove `async`).

Comment: @WiktorZychla `return Task.CompletedTask` will result in `Task<Task>` return type for this method.

Comment: `await Task.CompletedTask;` will complete synchronously: it's safe to remove that line. It was probably added before doing any actual async invocation within the method.

Comment: @WiktorZychla completely agree, I would not care so much if it would have been a return, but it is just awaiting something that is completed. I wonder if I am missing something...

Comment: @meJustAndrew it should be safe to remove that code.

Comment: @meJustAndrew: have you seen this pattern somewhere? What's the original cause of your doubts?

Comment: @WiktorZychla it is the first time I have seen this async, but I wonder if it will keep waiting for the current Task to change its state or something like this. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59867966/does-await-task-completedtask-do-anything) (which is similar to mine, I know) and it made me more confused than I was before, so I don't know...

Comment: @meJustAndrew: you should not be confused. An async function *yields* when it returns and lets the calling context execute. As Stephen points out, `Task.Yield()` should be used. But you really don't need this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly safe to remove that. 
This call doesn't do anything there other than checking that the task is already completed.

Years ago, when `async` was not yet available but `Task` was, we had to have

```
public Task Something()
{
    ....

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

People adopted this when `Task.CompletedTask` was added and you will often see

```
public Task Something()
{
    ....

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

This is something that makes sense if `....` doesn't do anything async but you still have to return a `Task`.

When `async` is available and the method body `await`s, the method doesn't have to return anything:

```
public async Task Something()
{
    await SomethingElse();        
}
```

But `await`ing the `Task.CompletedTask` - I don't think there's a scenario where this would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the line `await Task.CompletedTask;` is an easy way to suppress the compiler warning [CS1998](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243975/suppress-warning-cs1998-this-async-method-lacks-await):

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

Other than that it does nothing. So it is quite possible to add it while designing the API of a class, and then forget to remove it after writting the implementation. Feel free to remove it. Removing it will not cause any side-effects at all.